# C++ comparator guarantees and inner workings

Tags: c++, operators, standards

Solving [this problem](https://icpcarchive.ecs.baylor.edu/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=4168), I found that

```
if(!(p<arr[i]))
```

and

```
if(p>=arr[i])
```

May have different results(`p` is a `long long` and `arr[i]` is a `double` ), since the first solution is accepted and the second is not. Why?

Complete code for context:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define EPS (1e-5)
using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;
double arr[10005];
int main(){
    ll D,p;
    string s;
    while(getline(cin,s)){
        stringstream ss(s);
        ss>>D>>p;
        int n=0;
        while(ss>>arr[n]) ++n;
        ll dmin=D+1;
        if(n<D+1){
            double a=arr[n-4];
            double b=arr[n-3];
            double c=arr[n-2];
            double d=arr[n-1];
            double den=a*c-b*b;
            double s=(c*c-b*d)/den;
            double t=(a*d-b*c)/den;
            for(int i=n;i<=D;++i)
                arr[i]=s*arr[i-2]+t*arr[i-1];
        }
        for(int i=0;i<=D;++i){
            if(!(p<arr[i]))
                dmin=min(dmin,D-i);
            else
                break;
        }
        if(dmin==0) cout<<"The spider may fall!"<<endl;
        else if(dmin==D+1) cout<<"The spider is going to fall!"<<endl;
        else cout<<dmin<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `!(a<b)` and `(a>=b)` are different then the most likely explanation is that one of them is a NaN. *Any* comparison involving a NaN results in `false`, so if `b` is a NaN, then both `(a<b)` and `(a>=b)` will be false, and `!(a<b)` will be true.

Looking at your code, first:

```
double den=a*c-b*b;
double s=(c*c-b*d)/den;
double t=(a*d-b*c)/den;
```

There is no obvious reason why `den` cannot be zero, in which case both `s` and `t` will be infinities. Then, you compute:

```
for(int i=n;i<=D;++i)
  arr[i]=s*arr[i-2]+t*arr[i-1];
```

If `s` and `t` are inifinities, then there is ample room for the sum which produces `arr[i]` to be a NaN. The sum of two infinities of the same sign is the infinity itself, but the sum of two infinities of opposite signs is a NaN. Also, the product of 0 and infinity is a NaN.

And once a NaN gets into `arr`, it will propagate, since each element depends on the previous one.

So you probably need to do something if `den` is 0.